# Getting a loaded SCRIPT variable in nightmarejs

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I want to get the value from a loaded `script.js` when using `.evaluate()` in nightmare. So let's say there is this basic html on some website...

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title> far-away-website.com</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
 <script src="script-two.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div> DOM stuff</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it's `script.js` has this...

```
​func.prototype.hasData = function() {
                return this.data
            }
```

​
How can I get the value of `this.data` from `.evaluate()` in nightmarejs?...

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
    // waitTimeout: 60000, // in ms
    openDevTools: {
        //mode: 'detach'
    },
    show: true
})
nightmare.goto('https://www.far-away-website.com')

    .evaluate(() => {
            return this.data // needed from script.js
    })

.then((data) => {
console.log(data)
})
```

P.S. The value of `this.data` can be seen using `watch` in chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

The following code simply shows that `this` refers to only that object. If that object is in global window, you can access it by creating a object and using the `.hasData()` function property.

Otherwise you cannot access `this.data` since it's in a different function scope. You can read more about how you can take advantage of that by reading some materials.

Also, you did not share a real working website/code, cannot help much without that.

Read more about this, [here](https://toddmotto.com/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript/) and [here](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).
Read more about scopes, [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript).